# How to display all links of the Answers module on a single page?

Tags: views, navigation, 7

I using the [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) module, which provide the various set of views as shown in the image below. But it does not provide anything where we can provide these views as a link. **I mean I want all these four views in one line as a menu tabs on page**,

So, it should be like this:

- Main menu tab: `Q&A`
- When this Q&A tab is clicked, it should show all these 4 tabs with first tab as default:

  > All Questions | Unanswered Questions | Search Questions | Search & Add Page

I am surprised this option is not available by default.

[image]

Comment: How did you create the Unanswered Questions and Search & Add Page displays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the (new) [demo site](http://drupal.placeto.be/module/answers) of the [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) module (disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of it). Consider this [demo site](http://drupal.placeto.be/module/answers) link as the equivalent of what you named "main menu Q&A". Visiting that link will show various menu options within the block with title ***Answers Menu***, i.e.:

- **Questions** (= a view):

  - **All**: of all existing questions (= default tab).
  - **Answered**: all questions which have a "best" (= accepted) answer (= sub-tab).
  - **Unanswered**: all questions which do not yet have a "best" (= accepted) answer (= sub-tab).
- **Answers** (= a view): lists all existing answers for any of the existing questions and which does not (yet) have any submenu options (implemented as tabs).
- **Rankings** (= a view): contains a list of users with their actual ranking (= reputation points implemented via user points), and with each user a link to either the questions or answers from that user.
- **Ask Question**: to post a new question (the equivalent of `node/add/question`), which is only shown for authenticated users though.

These views also use the [dataTables](https://www.drupal.org/project/datatables) format, but you could easily replace that with any views display format you'd want. And because of the search box that comes with dataTables, there is no need for extra menu links to search within questions, answers or rankers.

These new/enhanced views were created starting from the 7.x-4.x-rc2 release of [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers), and will be included in the next release of it also (together with various other enhancements not yet visibile in the demo site). Which should address your "***I am surprised this option is not available by default***" also, no?

Comment: Very thanks for the answer, I will check the 7.x-4.x-rc2 release. I have other points and features to point out for this module, but first I will check this release, if feature is there, ok, otherwise I will add under the documentation on drupal.org or under issue. Thanks

Comment: OK, great (+ merci for accept) ... See you in the issue queue!?!?!?

Comment: Hi Pierre, Can we use 7.x-4.x-rc2 release for the production site. I checked this one, and compared to the current 7.x-3.2 release, its user interface is very well organized and very clean, even I liked the plain theme (without activating Answers theme) which is very clear. But still it does not have feature of All question | Unanswered question | Search Question | Search and Add Page AND Tagging like stakexchange. I guess It is to be included in other release as you have describe in above answer. However, is there any way we can achieve this and can go ahead. Very Thanks

Comment: @codenext : 7.x-4.x is a major rewrite of the 7.x-3.x version. The 7.x-4.x-rc2 is pretty "stable", and personally I'm only aware of [1 showstopper](https://www.drupal.org/node/2688325#comment-10974741) that I believe needs to be fixed (at least) prior to a 7.x-4.0 release (help wanted!). Apart from that, there are still a few 3.x functionalities (features) that didn't make it yet in 4.x, but those might get added soon in something like a 4.1, 4.2 etc release afterwards. The major advantage of going with the 7.x-4.x (for a new site) is that you avoid the challenge to "migrate" from 7.x-3.x.

Comment: Hhmmm...thanks for the information on releases. Wish I would have provided the help, but I do not have any background of codes, this is my first website and all I am doing is try and error method and this way I am learning. However, I will take a look there, if I can do anything. but surely, in future I will provide the help as much I can. Very thanks

Comment: @CodeNext : did you ever had a chance to experiment with the 4.x-rc2 version I recommended before? If so, did you enable voting? And if so, did you get the "downvoting" (either for questions or answers) to work? FYI: upvoting and cancelling upvotes works fine in my setup. This is about my only showstopper to prepare for a (final?) RC3 version of it ...

Comment: Hi, At that time I even had tried all three version of module i.e. 7.x-3.2, 7.x-4.0-rc2, 7.x-4.x-dev. But the particular Voting feature was not in question as at that time I was checking the particular main Tabs as described in my question. However, I will check that version 4.x-rc2 and let you know on that.

Comment: I did check the feature, Upvoting and DownVoting both are working. Other observations:  It only shows up after page refresh. And it is appearing only in Questions and Answers node, but not in comment, I have enabled it for comments. And in comments- Delete and Edit option are not working. Might these information helps.

Comment: 4.x-rc2 version

Comment: aha, that's good to know ... the version I'm working with is based on Version: 7.x-4.0-rc2+2-dev ... with on top of that some things I've been working on (like the newest views) which I've not published on D.O yet, like I said before, I think, this downvoting thing is for me the showstopper (a prereq to get sorted out). Anyway, you gave me some ideas for further debugging (= how come it works in RC2, and no longer in my site), so merci!

Answer (score 1):

The [Panels module](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) allows you to create "pages" of blended content at an URL or URL with a context argument (like a node ID). For example an arbitrary node, 4 views, a custom text panel and a block. It's extremely flexible and fairly easy to learn. Once you've learned the basics you'll never build a site without it.

[Panels module](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels)

Comment: Hhmmm...I am in learning process for panels, will try it, but agree that this can be done by panels, meanwhile I did some try in views and find the solution which I have posted. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some try and error, I myself found the answer, but do not know this is the right way to do or not, but it is working.

1. `Search Question` and `Search & Add Page` does not have any menu link in the Menu option under the `Page setting` for their views, So, just provided `Menu tab` and provided the title, hence now it is showing the all four tabs in one line.
2. Main Menu tab: I just added the tab in the main menu as Q&A and provided the path `/questions` which is the path of first tab, hence when person clicks `Q&A`, it just lead to first page of `All Questions`.

Please correct if there is a better way to do this.